# Why can't we use one of the characteristic roots instead of both?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''+5y'+6y=0, IC: y(0)=2, y'(0)=3$

Characteristic equation: $(y+3)(y+2)=0$

Thus $y=c_1e^{-3t}+c_2e^{2t}\to y=9e^{-2t}-7e^{-3t}$

My question is why can we not use just one of the root solutions for the solution (instead of being a linear combination of two terms)? E.g. $r=-3$:

$y=ce^{-3t}$, since it still satisfies the original DE:

$y''+5y'+6y=0\to9ce^{-3t}-15ce^{-3t}+6ce^{-3t}=0$, with I.C. $\to y=2e^{-3t}$

The first solution $y=9e^{-2t}-7e^{-3t}$ and the second solution $y=2e^{-3t}$ are clearly not equivalent, but why is this so, since all of the work up until this point was valid? Also, I noticed that the second IC was not able to be used when using just one root. Is this part of the reason?

Answer (score 4):

You can use just one, but it's not a complete solution, and does not describe all possible forms a solution to the ODE might take. Taking only one root describes the general case when one of your $c_1,c_2$ are equal to $0$.

It's like claiming $x^2 = 1$ means $x=1$. You're not wrong, but you're not fully describing the solution set.

> Also, I noticed that the second IC was not able to be used when using just one root. Is this part of the reason?

The reason you have two initial conditions is that, when solving an ODE of the $n$th order, and you give a full solution set, you need $n$ initial data points (be it for the function or its derivatives) to get rid of all of the arbitrary constants you get. You have a second-order ODE; hence, without initial data, a **complete** solution set is described up to two arbitrary constants. To determine what those two constants must be precisely, you'll need two initial data points to do so. (It essentially ties into linear dependence from linear algebra.)